# Can a sql server table have two identity columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity-column

I need to have one column as the primary key and another to auto increment an order number field. Is this possible?

EDIT: I think I'll just use a composite number as the order number. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo](
    [FooId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BarId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)
```

returns

```
Msg 2744, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Foo'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.
```

So, no, you can't have two identity columns. You can of course make the primary key not auto increment (identity).

Edit: [msdn:CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) and [CREATE TABLE (SQL Server 2000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

> Only one identity column can be created per table.

Comment: I tried this but often a setting can be changed which is why I asked the question.

Comment: It's by spec. See the added link to msdn.

Answer (score 22):

You can use Sequence for second column with default value IF you use SQL Server 2012

```
--Create the Test schema
CREATE SCHEMA Test ;
GO

-- Create a sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.SORT_ID_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO

-- Create a table
CREATE TABLE Test.Foo
    (PK_ID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SORT_ID int not null  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.SORT_ID_seq));
GO

INSERT INTO Test.Foo VALUES ( DEFAULT )
INSERT INTO Test.Foo VALUES ( DEFAULT )
INSERT INTO Test.Foo VALUES ( DEFAULT )

SELECT * FROM Test.Foo 

-- Cleanup
--DROP TABLE Test.Foo
--DROP SEQUENCE Test.SORT_ID_seq
--DROP SCHEMA Test
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx

Comment: Good suggestion, only problem is Truncation of the Table.

Comment: I'm not sure that Truncation is a problem, if you want to [reset sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx#code-snippet-7), you can easily do that

Comment: Yes but unlike the Identity identifier, you have to either drop the sequence and then re-add or go through and redefine the start for the sequence.  For development and/or testing, Sequence is not an ideal implementation.  Once you get past the dev/testing stage, it is a massively useful implementation.  Just a PITA during the dev-stages

Answer (score 9):

Add one identity column and then add a computed column whose formula is the name of the identity column

Now both will increment at the same time

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible to have more than one identity column.

The Enterprise Manager does not even allow you to set > 1 column as identity. When a second column is made identity

Also note that @@identity returns the last identity value for the open connection which would be meaningless if more than one identity column was possible for a table.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #tblStudent
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    Number UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(),
    Name nvarchar(50)
)
```

Two identity column is not possible but if you accept to use a unique identifier column then this code does the same job as well. And also you need an extra column - Name column- for inserting values.

Example usage:

```
insert into #tblStudent(Name) values('Ali')

select * from #tblStudent
```

---

Ps: [NewID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function creates a unique value of type uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key doesn't need to be an identity column.

You can't have two Identity columns.

You could get something close to what you want with a trigger...

Comment: This is problematic. A primary key does not allow null values. Usually auto-generated keys are left out on inserts. Even if you use a trigger with INSTEAD OF INSERT to generate your primary key it will puke (Tested on SQLSEVER2000)

Comment: @snmcdonald: Don't use SQL Server 2000 in 2011 year.

Answer (score 0):

in sql server it's not possible to have more than one column as identity.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a code that will allow you inserting two identities on the same table. let me share it with you in case it helps:

```
create trigger UpdateSecondTableIdentity
On TableName For INSERT
as
update TableName
set SecondIdentityColumn = 1000000+@@IDENTITY
where ForstId = @@IDENTITY;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In most relational databases like SQL Server, Oracle, or MySQL, **a table can typically have only one identity column**. An identity column is a column that automatically generates unique values when new rows are added to the table.

Having multiple identity columns within a table would create ambiguity regarding which column serves as the primary key.
However, you can achieve similar functionality by using other approaches, such as:

1. Composite Keys:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ProductID INT,
    Quantity INT,
    -- Other columns related to orders

    CONSTRAINT PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, ProductID)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

A workaround would be to create an INSERT Trigger that increments a counter.

So I have a table that has one identity col : applicationstatusid. its also the primary key.
I want to auto increment another col: applicationnumber

So this is the trigger I write.

```
 create trigger [applicationstatus_insert] on [ApplicationStatus] after insert as 
       update [Applicationstatus] 
       set [Applicationstatus].applicationnumber =(applicationstatusid+ 4000000) 
       from [Applicationstatus] 
       inner join inserted on [applicationstatus].applicationstatusid = inserted.applicationstatusid
```

Comment: CREATE Sequence below allows you to make a default value that auto-increments. Before 2012 you could use a function that increments a value in a table and returns it (similar to what you have done in your answer). And that could be a default value for a column. Triggers should be avoided.