# Auto-incrementing a non-identity field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to auto-increment a field that is not defined as `Primary Key` in a table?

Lets say that i have three fields in a table.  One of them is `Primary Key` with `IDENTITY(1,1)` set.

The second field is a `int` type that i want to auto-increment with a `INSERT` statement on a third field called column_3.

So for example: `INSERT INTO table_name(column_3) values('something')`

I could easily add a trigger for this but i was wondering if there is a way of doing this without a trigger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349092/can-a-sql-server-table-have-two-identity-columns?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: you cannot have 2 identity columns and there is one big reason for this - you don't need this, there is no sense in 2 columns which will have the same value

Comment: right, I'm not asking for second IDENTITY column or them having same values.  The PK can increment 1,1 the second one can be 100,1 or whatever as long as it is auto-incrementing

Comment: With a high enough version of sql server, you can use a sequence.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can create a table as given below for your purpose

```
CREATE TABLE [LUName]
(
id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name CHAR(25),
EmpID AS id + 100,
InsertTS DATETIME
)
```

The `INSERT` script will be as given below.

```
INSERT INTO [LUName] VALUES
('Bless',GETDATE()),('Sus',GETDATE()),('Sani',GETDATE()),('Sumi',GETDATE())
```

The resulting Data will be as given below.

```
SELECT * FROM [LUName]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a computed column, although then it will always be directly related to your IDENTITY column.

You can also so this in SQL Server 2012 or later with a SEQUENCE: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx

The whole concept seems rather odd to me, though.

Comment: I agree.  I found a way where I don't have to do this since it is odd.  But it is nice to know about what you guys explained in answers.  Thanks