# Convert exiting column into 2nd auto increment column

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, identity

in Sql Server I have a table StudentMaster in which I have One ID(Primary) column and other "StudentRollNo"(Not Primary) Column . I need to convert StudentRollNo as Another Identity Column .. I Tried this :

```
ALTER TABLE studentMaster alter column StudentRollNo AS ID + 0
```

But this is not working 'AS' and '+' are not acceptable in this Query . Is there any other Option in Sql Server ??

Comment: You cant have 2 identity keys in a table,I think you want an unique index `ALTER TABLE studentMaster  
ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint_name UNIQUE (StudentRollNo );`

Comment: StudentRollNo IS NOT PRIMARY

Comment: OR you want a sequence http://stackoverflow.com/a/22814247/1745672

Comment: this is for new column , I want  solution for existing column

Comment: Can you guide me how modify a column as Sequence Column

Comment: @NeerajVerma is you want to same ID value in `StudentRollNo` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq START WITH watever_number INCREMENT BY 1;

ALTER TABLE studentMaster ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name 
      DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR seq FOR StudentRollNo
```

Replace watever_number with the highest value in your column

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Computed column](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-computed-column-calculated-column-sample.aspx) on your database table

```
alter table TableName add ComputedColumnName as Id -- Identity column name
```